# What's the best way to update a GoogleMap map with markers that come from the server?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currntly working on a project that uses Google Maps API for Android. In my MapActivity, I have to distribute all the marker that are in the polygon for the current visible area. My problem is, to get the coordinates from the server, I run a new thread with AsyncTask everytime the user moves the camera, but as it runs off the UI thread, when I get the result from AsyncTask using `MyTask.execute(params).get();`, my map gets really lagged and slow and eventually crashes my app. So, what's the best way to do what I want without crashing the app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#viewportmarkermanagement) article would greatly help you with your concern. You can check out the Viewport Marker Management section of the article. Basically its just showing the Markers that are in the user's current viewable area. As the user pans/zooms it subsequent request to the server to retrieve new markers, other markers that are not in view are removed.